# Disconnect a adapter

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7

windows7, we can see different adapters in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections", ex: 3g modem, mobile data connection, ethernet, vpn etc...I think some of these are ras connections. Say if there is a connection made on "abc modem"(ras modem) using some program given by vendor, then you can right click on adapter and disconnect. 
Is there a api available for this disconnect process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RasHangUp Function solved my problem. Though, i'm not so sure about consequences.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377567(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can administratively shutdown the adapter with the `SetIfEntry` function. You pass a `MIB_IFROW` structure that you get filled with `GetIfEntry` before but with a changed `dwAdminStatus` member value.

You will need the IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER ioctl call to enable the addapter again.

Comment: I donot want to shutdown, disconnect should be sufficient. in that case, i need disable and enable? will this enable leaves adapter in disconnected state?